# ASP.NET application deployment requirements

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment

I am in the middle of developing my first C# ASP.NET (v 4.5.2) Web API, and until now i have been only using Visual Studio 2015 Professional, with IIS Express 10 for debugging.
I have no previous experience with IIS or ASP.NET deployment in general.
So my questions :

1. When i publish my application and try to deploy it on the production IIS (which will probably be IIS v.8), am i going to need any .Net frameworks or any other packages manually installed on the server? What about any Nuget packages i use? Does the publishing process wrap all the needed files?
2. Which version of IIS am i going to need in order for my
   application to work?
3. Are there any other considerations to ensure that an ASP.NET app will be
   deployed successfully on a production environment? Like if i use MVC
   or Entity Framework do i need to install those manually on the
   server?
4. **EDIT :** Forgot about Crystal Reports! I suppose this has to be manually installed on the server right?

Comment: As far as I know you need web deploy on the server. https://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later As far as the other things go. Framework 4.5 needs to be installed on the server and the Nuget packages are just dll's which are automatically sent to the server on deploy.

Comment: Useful link, seems that there is an automated tool (Web Platform Installer) that, contains web deploy and other useful server side packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

if you take a new version of IIS you should not have to install .net frameworks. If the target framework does not exist on that server, you have to install it and register for iis : https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

The nuget packages won't be a problem because Vs will deploy all dlls too (like on express)

If you are using some special things like Url-Rewrite you have to install these modules manually (e.g. for url-rewrite https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

2.

About the version, if you want to do it easy, just use the newest. But it depends on which server-version do you use, even though most applications work on older IIS too. Maybe some changes in the web.config have to be made if you are using some kind of "special" configurations

3.

For deployment you have several options:

- Webdeploy (https://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later)
- Deployment over FTP/Fileshare - create on IIS an Application - ensure that the right .net framework is selected - create fileshare or ftp - then deploy it into the directory, which is app-directory

Comment: Thank you @user1519979 that was fast! Do you know anything about Crystal Reports also? I have just updated my question, sorry about that.

Comment: have not used CrystalReports on IIS directly yet. But as i know you just have to install the runitme for it - maybe this will help you http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-deploy.htm or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287928(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: FWIW, i did a fast publish-deploy on my development box using the suggested tools and it seems that all the Crystal Reports DLLs where published on the deployed directory. That could mean that no extra manual installation is required, but i should test it on a staging server also...