# Can I deploy web-form asp.net web application to google cloud?

Tags: asp.net, google-cloud-platform, webforms

I created a new Asp.net webform application and trying to deploy it on google cloud but it's not giving me the option(Publish to google cloud) to deploy on GCP. Does anyone has deployed an existing ASP.net Webform application on GCP?

Comment: What are you publishing to? ASP.NET requires Windows. Most Google services such as App Engine, Cloud Run run Linux. You can publish to Compute Engine running Windows Server.

Comment: On Windows server only

Answer (score 1):

You can run various code on Google App Engine but in case of ASP.net it's exactly as [@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) wrote:

> ASP.NET requires Windows. Most Google services such as App Engine,
> Cloud Run run Linux. You can publish to Compute Engine running Windows
> Server.

You need to set up a Windows Server instance and install everything you need there. If you have any licenced software you will need proper licences - GCP [can provide only Windows licences](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/ms-licensing#on-demand).

There is a simillar question that was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805080/asp-net-application-deployment-requirements) that you may find usefull.

Comment: Thanks All for your valuable feedback.. This problem is solved we can deploy the existing app to GCP.

Comment: Can you describe how you did that ? It will be more usefull to the community to have a good answer.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine?hl=en_US